how to solve scalability issues with SingleStore DB License Capacity in CI/CD Pipeline over time
Our development stack relies on SingleStore DB, and for testing purposes, we utilize a straightforward Docker-compose setup with MemSQL, executing Mocha tests. Initially, our CI pipeline functioned smoothly with a free license. However, as our team expanded, sporadic failures emerged within CI jobs.
Upon investigation, we discovered that when the license capacity was reached, the SingleStore container failed to initiate a new leaf, resulting in container crashes. This impedes the scalability of our CI jobs and UAT environments, which are reliant on this license.
As a temporary measure, I successfully ran the test code against a MySQL container, yielding satisfactory results. However, I seek insight into how other companies have addressed similar challenges. It appears that aside from scaling the license over time, alternative solutions lack the scalability required. Any suggestions or best practices would be greatly appreciated.

change the docker compose only for testing to run against mysql container
create pull of free license and use different key for every job


You have few options to resolve your issue:

Request increase your license capacity for POC (Contact us)
Try unlimited capacity
Purchase the license for bigger capacity (Contact us)

Steps how to to increase capacity your license:

Login portal portal.singlestore.com
Find your org menu on the left side



Click Self-Managed license



thanks !

i want to say i really love your product
i think there is a conflict with your solution
i want to add a lot of tests and thats means if i want to add more coverage to my code base i need to pay more money to single store

